# Need assistance to find the syntax error in my query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm writing a program to manipulating time entries by users. I wrote the below PHP to retrieve user details from the server when the variables are push from a JavaScript.

My problem is the SQL is throwing a fatal error which ways it near the variable :uid.

Here is the complete error I'm getting,

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':uid' at line 1' in ***\TimSheetSystem\bin\Functions\getUsrId.php on line 25

Here is my javascript,

```
function getUser2(){

var selUser = document.getElementById("uid").value;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("userSelect").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST","../functions/getUsrId.php?uid=getUsr2&selUser="+selUser,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

And here is the PHP with the query,

```
$getSelUsr = "SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE uId = :uid";
$getSelUsrQuery = $dbConnect -> query($getSelUsr);
$getSelUsrQuery -> bindParam(':uid', $_REQUEST["selUser"]);
$getSelUsrQuery -> execute();
$getSelUsrRow = $getSelUsrQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<option id= ".$getSelUsrRow["uId"].">".$getSelUsrRow["fName"]." ".$getSelUsrRow["lName"]."</option>";
```

I looked and checked all the semi's and did try to push the data directly with out the JavaScript but still I'be getting the same error over and over.

Can some one spot what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT1**
This is page calls the getUser2 function via a timed function caller.

The main page,

```
<?php if ($_SESSION["sT"] == "Done"){ ?>
 <body onload="tEditReload2()">
 <div id="divCenter-timeEdit" class="box">
  <label id="sbId" hidden><?php echo $_SESSION["uRole"]?></label>
   <div class="logo-timeEdit">
        <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33">
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv" style="height: 38px;">
        <label for="dPicker">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="dPicker" style="margin-left: .5%;" size="10" value="<?php echo $getStermRow["sDate"]; ?>">
        <label for="userSelect" style="margin-left: 2%">Select User:</label>
        <select id="userSelect" style="width:160px; margin-left: .5%;" onchange="usrId(this.id);"></select>
        <input type="text" id="uid" size="1" value="<?php echo $getStermRow["sUid"]; ?>" hidden>
 <input type="button" class="getData" value="Submit" onclick="getData();">
    </div>
    <div id="resultTable"><span id="noDataMsg"></span> </div>2
</div>
</body>
```

Timed function caller,

```
function tEditReload2() {
    getUser2();
    setTimeout("getData();",100);
}
```

Comment: `:uid` looks suspect. Can you post the part with `$uid = $_POST["uid"]` - there is likely no JavaScript involved in the problem - looks like a typo

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("POST","../functions/getUsrId.php?uid=getUsr2&selUser="+selUser,true);` is this what you asking for ?

Comment: No - where in the PHP do you get the `uid`

Comment: try using `bindValue`    http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: On $_REQUEST["selUser"], line 3

Comment: Definitely it sql error .You have to check sql query.Please dump the request array to check weather "selUser"  is exist .

Comment: Are you logging queries launched to DB?

Comment: Thank you for the over whelming help guys have been look at the code since morning it was a very stupid over look after copy pasting my own code. forgot to change `query()` to `prepared()`.

Comment: voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: I agree with @mplungjan this won't help future users so please do close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change:

```
$getSelUsrQuery = $dbConnect -> query($getSelUsr);
```

to

```
$getSelUsrQuery = $dbConnect ->prepare($getSelUsr);
```

Have you dumped the $uid? Is it a valid value?

Comment: Again a very bad over look after copy pasting my own code from another function. it was the `query()` which should be `prepare()` I can be very stupid after looking at code all day thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try `bindValue` insted `bindParam`

```
$getSelUsrQuery -> bindValue(':uid', $_REQUEST["selUser"]);
```